# Using SignTool for Excel add-ins

Tags: digital-signature, signtool, authenticode

I want to use Sign Tool from Windows SDK on my Excel Add-in project.

The signing works fine on the installer, but when I try on the dll-files it has no effect. I tried signing the vsto-file instead but then I get "This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized".

The signing certificate is on a usb-dongle and I use the following command for the signing:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /debug /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a myInstaller.exe`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that could be wrong here. Your parameters look good but the /a switch can get confused if there are multiple suitable certs in your store. Try using the /f switch to specify the certificate exactly.

Its tricky to tell if this is your problem. Perhaps you could share the debug output? Are there any error messages? Does the dll have a proper PE header, have you tried signing other dlls?